# When we use OCR using Adobe Acrobat 2017 Not picking up same text on same page multiple times

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

When I use OCR using Adobe Acrobat 2017  I'm finding that it is not picking up the same text on the same page.  For instance when we have the word Dr. Thandabout 15 times on the same page, it only picks this name up 12 times. Can someone provide guidance on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

OCRing is never 100% accurate and an editorial review should be done after a PDF's OCR.

From my experience estimated (opinionated) with OCR results:

- sans-serif: 95% accurate
- serif: 90% accurate
- monospaced font: 80% accurate
- decorative serif: 75% accurate
- cursive: 50% accurate

Of course the above estimates are only if the PDF wasn't scanned and is just an image based PDF without trash.

If you cannot run the PDF through editorial you could always check spelling by pressing the <kbd>F7</kbd> key or use `Edit => Check Spelling => In Fields, Comment, Editable Text`

Comment: This is the most likely answer. OCR is asking a computer to pretend it has eyes and make guesses about what is on a page. It uses algorithms and other cool things to do this. And running the same page through the same tool multiple times WILL result in variance because of the nature of the process.